# How to apply Logistic Regression Model in Test Data

Tags: logistic-regression

I had a Titanic Data set which had two parts- Train Data and Test Data. 
I have developed a model on Training Data set after missing value and outlier treatment.

Now I have to apply the model on Test Data set, So do I need to do the missing value treatment and outlier treatment on this data as well before applying the model.
And will it be the same process whenever I have to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the scenario you are trying to solve. Usually, I try to apply data pre-processing for test data as well, this is because I want to compare the accuracy of the two models (I want them to be similar). But just in case, if you want to see the performance of your regression against outliers as well, then you can try that out.

In case of prediction data, I think you should do the missing value treatment and, outlier treatment if possible. This is because if you can tag something as an outlier then you can avoid running them against the model and getting weird results. But in most production scenarios its difficult to predict something is an outlier and so I usually don't do outlier cleanups.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yes I will do the same type of cleanup in both the files.